# Save logs to file with Spring Boot. Issue: Log4j do not log to file when I use @Slf4j

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

I use Slf4j with the spring boot project. I managed log4j.properties, and have logs in the console, but can't implement logging to the file.

`log4j.properties`:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ERROR, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.dir}/Log4j/log4j-test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-4p] %d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss} %t | %m%n

log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
com.sun.jndi.rmi.object.trustURLCodebase=false
com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.object.trustURLCodebase=false
```

Also, I tried such options:

```
log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.fileName=Log4j/log4j-test.log
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
```

Logging example:

```
@Slf4j
public class A{
    public void m(){
        log.info("log");
    }
}
```

- Dependency supplied with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.6:`

In any case, I haven't a file in the result.

How to correctly create logging to the file with this solution?

Comment: And what makes you think `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging` is for `log4j`? log4j support has been dropped some time ago, log4j2 support is still there however that requires an XML file to configure.

Comment: By default, Spring Boot uses logback, not log4j.

Comment: @RobSpoor so, do I need to include log4j dependency? I did it, but nothing changed. And in addition - it seems the Slf4j doesn't read log4j.properties. So, I agree with you, but how to solve this issue? Can I use Slf4j annotation instead Logger class for logging into the file?

Comment: If you want to use log4j 1.x, I'd go for reload4j. It's a fork that fixes some bugs, and is still maintained unlike log4j 1.x itself. I think you can add `slf4j-reload4j` as dependency, but you must also exclude any logback dependency, which probably is a transitive dependency. Otherwise you have two different SLF4J bindings which also won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

1.

First of all, we need to exclude logback from the dependencies.
Lockback is included in the `spring-boot-starter-web` and we can do it with gradle in the following way:

```
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${spring_boot_version}"){
        exclude group:"org.apache.logging.log4j", module:"log4j-to-slf4j"
    }
```

In my case, the `logback` also supplied with `spring-boot-starter-validation` and in some reason gradle doesn't want to exclude `logback` from the both dependenisies. The working solution in this case is adding exclusion in the `configurations` block:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}
```

2. 

I added `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` dependency:

```
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
```

3. 

I created `log4j2-spring.xml` file in resources directory:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="./logs/spring-boot-logger-log4j2.log"
                     filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/spring-boot-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <!-- rollover on startup, daily and when the file reaches
                    10 MegaBytes -->
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="10 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>

        <!-- LOG "com.proxy*" at TRACE level -->
        <Logger name="com.proxy" level="trace"></Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

---

PS. This solution tested with `spring_boot_version = '2.6.6'`

Comment: To remove all "x to Logback" bridges: 1. add [`spring-boot-starter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter) explicitly (it is a common dependency of most starters), 2. exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` from `spring-boot-starter`. This should cut the dependency paths to all Logback-related artifacts.